# Chrome out of memory

Tags: windows, memory, settings, freeze, lag

I just updated my windows 11. I can't open chrome because out of memory, i watch many tutorial and now my chrome can't open. How to fix it?

I have try so many tutorial and it just became more sucks

Answer (score 0):

After the Chrome update, it gives an out of memory error to the pages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).